# How can I generate PDF file in python on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I am following these instructions:

https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab

but i am getting this error:

```
Couldn't load plugin Importtool due to an error when calling its classFactory() method


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .Import_tool import Importtool

  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

  File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 39, in 
    import reportlab

  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import

    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named reportlab
```

Comment: It seems you have installed the reportlab package in a standard way, that is outside the QGIS folder. Running QGIS, it will not see that installation.

Answer (score 2):

Download http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py. 
Open your osgeo shell as admin - use the one associated with your QGIS install if you have more than one installed.

run:

```
python ez_setup.py
```

then

```
cd "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Scripts"
easy_install pip
pip install reportlab
```

Some of this I got from http://nathanw.net/2012/12/19/installing-python-setuptools-into-osgeo4w-python/.
You'll need to change the QGIS directory for your system if it's different.

Comment: I suggest to put the path into quotation marks. Otherwise you will stumble over the blanks.

Comment: @AndreJ You're absolutely right. I added the quotes. Thanks.